# Errors with Codename One "Send iOS Build" and "Send Android Build"

Tags: codenameone

I had no problem with "Build Project"/"Rebuid Project" using IntelliJ IDEA for my Codename One project.

Today, I just started to "Send iOS Build" and "Send Android Build" and got a spew of errors.

For the one below, I cannot recognize why it failed, or where to find the "compiler error output" as described:

[image]

For this next one, I can recognize it is referring to the java.time package (Java 8):

[image]

I saw somewhere that I should include the "java.version=8" and I already did.

Please help me to get my iOS and Android builds. Thanks!

Comment: In addition to the correct answer from @Diamond notice that you can toggle text mode in the top left portion of the error log. It's sometimes clearer than those messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the StackTrace above, you are using some java API that Codename One doesn't support like the `GregorianCalendar` and `LocalDateTime`. You can read more about this here...[why-we-dont-support-the-full-java-api](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/why-we-dont-support-the-full-java-api.html)

You can ask a separate question on what you're trying to achieve with those and maybe someone here could provide you with an alternative solution that will work.