# Layout issue with Codename One

Tags: codenameone

At this moment I'm only testing my app in the simulator (as I'm having issues with "Send iOS Build" mentioned in another thread [[Errors with Codename One "Send iOS Build" and "Send Android Build"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42860517/errors-with-codename-one-send-ios-build-and-send-android-build]))

I'm experiencing some layout issues where it is not making use of the width and height correctly. The elements are left-aligned and there is **unused space on the right side**. And I **need to scroll up and down** instead of having everything fit within the visual area. Please see images.

[image]

[image]

The code are:

```
private final void show() {
    loginSignupForm = new Form("Company", new BoxLayout(0));
    Tabs loginSignupTabs = new Tabs();
    Style loginSignupStyle = UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("Tab");
    prepareAndAddSignupTab(loginSignupTabs, loginSignupStyle);
    prepareAndAddLoginTab(loginSignupTabs, loginSignupStyle);
    loginSignupForm.add(loginSignupTabs);
    loginSignupForm.show();
}

private void prepareAndAddLoginTab(Tabs loginSignupTabs, Style loginSignupStyle) {
    loginID = new TextField();
    loginPassword = new TextField();
    Button loginButton = getLoginButton();
    Component[] loginComponents = {
            new Label("Email Address"),
            loginID,
            new Label("Password"),
            loginPassword,
            loginButton,
    };
    Container loginContainer = BoxLayout.encloseY(loginComponents);
    FontImage loginIcon = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_QUESTION_ANSWER, loginSignupStyle);
    loginSignupTabs.addTab("Login", loginIcon, loginContainer);
}
```

What do I need to changenter code heree to get the elements to:

```
1. expand to the maximum width (no free space on the right)
2. fit within the visual area (for top-to-bottom)
```

Please note that I'm coding the elements because I find the (new) GUI Builder quite a challenge to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, don't pass a constant value as an argument to Layouts, coz the values might change in future Codename One updates and this will be difficult for you to debug. `new BoxLayout(0)` should be `new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS)` or simply `BoxLayout.y()`.

The above is where the problem arose but not the only problem because `BoxLayout` doesn't recognize `0` as a valid argument as it has only 3 which are `X_AXIS = 1`, `Y_AXIS = 2`, and `X_AXIS_NO_GROW = 3`.

If you change the above to use `BoxLayout.Y_AXIS`, it will work, but from the screenshot above, that's not the best solution.

In conclusion, change your code to below:

```
private final void show() {
    loginSignupForm = new Form("Company", new BorderLayout());
    Tabs loginSignupTabs = new Tabs();
    Style loginSignupStyle = UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("Tab");
    prepareAndAddSignupTab(loginSignupTabs, loginSignupStyle);
    prepareAndAddLoginTab(loginSignupTabs, loginSignupStyle);
    loginSignupForm.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, loginSignupTabs);
    loginSignupForm.show();
}
```